# Reading .doc file in Python using antiword in Windows (also .docx)

Tags: python, docx, doc

I tried reading a `.doc` file like -

```
with open('file.doc', errors='ignore') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

It did read that file but with huge junk, I can't remove that junk as I don't know from where it starts and where it ends.

I also tried installing `textract` module which says it can read from any file format but there were many dependency issues while downloading it in Windows.

So I alternately did this with `antiword` command line utility, my answer is below.

Comment: `doc` is an obsolete binary format. `docx` is a *zip* file containing XML documents. You can't just read either of them as if they were text files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had to do text classification task based on content of the file using ML. I have files with .pdf .doc .docx and .txt extension. I did this to get text content from files, am I wrong? If so then how am I suppose to classify the text if I can not read it from files. Please clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `antiword` command line utility to do this, I know most of you would have tried it but still I wanted to share.

- Download `antiword` from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/Antiword.shtml)

- Extract the `antiword` folder to `C:\` and add the path `C:\antiword` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Here is a sample of how to use it, handling docx and doc files:

```
import os, docx2txt
def get_doc_text(filepath, file):
    if file.endswith('.docx'):
       text = docx2txt.process(file)
       return text
    elif file.endswith('.doc'):
       # converting .doc to .docx
       doc_file = filepath + file
       docx_file = filepath + file + 'x'
       if not os.path.exists(docx_file):
          os.system('antiword ' + doc_file + ' > ' + docx_file)
          with open(docx_file) as f:
             text = f.read()
          os.remove(docx_file) #docx_file was just to read, so deleting
       else:
          # already a file with same name as doc exists having docx extension, 
          # which means it is a different file, so we cant read it
          print('Info : file with same name of doc exists having docx extension, so we cant read it')
          text = ''
       return text
```

Now call this function:

```
filepath = "D:\\input\\"
files = os.listdir(filepath)
for file in files:
    text = get_doc_text(filepath, file)
    print(text)
```

This could be good alternate way to read `.doc` file in `Python` on `Windows`.

Hope it helps, Thanks.

Comment: It seems like it would be more simple to use `subprocess.check_output` here and get the output from antiword, rather than saving it as docx.  From my usage, it seems like antiword isn't able to convert a doc file to docx.  Have you found differently?

Comment: The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions such as os.system. In my case conversion to .docx file was mandatory because I did not find any way to directly read from them.

Comment: This works on 64-bit windows, so it must be a 64-bit version of antiword. But it's not linked from the official site.

Answer (score 2):

Mithilesh's example is good, but it's simpler to directly use `textract` once you have antiword installed. Download [antiword](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/Antiword.shtml), and extract the antiword folder to `C:\`. Then add the antiword folder to your `PATH` environment variable. ([instructions for adding to PATH here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)). Open a new terminal or command console to re-load your `PATH` env variable. Install textract with `pip install textract`.

Then you can use `textract` (which uses `antiword` for .doc files) like this:

```
import textract
text = textract.process('filename.doc')
text.decode('utf-8')  # converts from bytestring to string
```

If you are getting errors, try running the command `antiword` from a terminal/console to make sure it works. Also be sure the filepath to the .doc file is correct (e.g. use `os.path.exists('filename.doc')`).