# How to bundle a program with auto-py-to-exe without changing PATH?

Tags: python, text-extraction, auto-py-to-exe, antiword

I want to include an external program with my Python program that I'll be turning into an .exe. The program is Antiword, which is used by `textract` to parse .doc files. If I have Antiword on my machine and modify the PATH environment variable to point to it, textract will use it correctly. (as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727237/reading-doc-file-in-python-using-antiword-in-windows-also-docx)).
However, I don't want my users to download Antiword separately and manually modify PATH. Can I include something in my main.py file, or during the auto-py-to-exe process so that Antiword comes bundled with it? Another acceptable solution would be for the program to add a new variable to PATH titled `MY_PROGRAM_ANTIWORD_PATH` with the correct location relative to the .exe.

Comment: you can use a config file to get this

Comment: Could you elaborate?